# How do I calculate the change in the argument of periapsis after a plane change maneuver?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, orbital-elements, polar-orbit

Let's say I have a spacecraft in an initial geocentric orbit with the following parameters: a = 7,960,000 m, e = 0.010, $\Omega$ = 180$^{\circ}$, i = 98$^{\circ}$, $\omega$ = 90$^{\circ}$, $\theta_0$ = 20$^{\circ}$.

I perform a plane change maneuver with $\theta$ = 1.19661$^{\circ}$ at a true anomaly f$_1$ = -48.1904$^{\circ}$ that alters my inclination to 98.8911$^{\circ}$ and my right ascension to 179.1926$^{\circ}$. Since it's a pure plane change, this shouldn't alter my semimajor axis or eccentricity, but I don't know how to calculate how this would change my spacecraft's argument of perigee or how to calculate my new true or mean anomaly from there.